# Border for the body content CSS, HTML

Tags: html, border, css

I struggle in making border for body content in HTML. I used:

```
-moz-border-image: url(/images/border.png) 20 repeat;
 -webkit-border-image: url(/images/border.png) 20 repeat;
 -o-border-image: url(/images/border.png) 20 repeat;
 border-image: url(/images/border.png) 20 repeat; 
 behavior: url(/css/PIE.htc);
```

...but because it is not working in explorer and even older versions of some other browsers, I have decided to come to old way of making it. However, I am not sure how to do that. We used have table in our old webpage like that:

```
<BODY leftmargin=0" topmargin=0" marginwidth=0" marginheight=0" class="content">
<TABLE align="center" width="880" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
    <TR>
        <TD><IMG src="/images/b-01-tl.jpg" alt="" width="20" height="20" border="0"><BR>
        </TD>
        <TD background="../images/b-01-mt.jpg" width="100%" valign="bottom">
        </TD>
        <TD><IMG src="/images/b-01-tr.jpg" alt="" width="20" height="20" border="0"><BR>
        </TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD background="../images/b-01-ml.jpg"><BR>
        </TD>
        <TD bgcolor="#000000" class="bg-w0">
```

..but now I created page with div and HTML5. Can anybody give idea how to implement new borders around content. We have 8 pictures of borders - top left, top line, top right, right line, bottom right, bottom line, bottom left and left line. I know it is possible to do it with div, however I don't find any tutorial how to do that. Waiting for any help :) If you need pictures of the borders, write me and I will upload it

Comment: You can make use of 3 divs: 1 for top containing the top/top-left/top-right border; 1 for the left/right borders; 1 for the bottom/bottom-left/bottom-right; 3 images all in all. The one in the middle is dynamically stretched to the height of the content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to do it the "old-fashioned way" eh, because border-image is bumming you out due to lack of support? Well, here's the old fashioned way, more or less:

```
<body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr valign="top">
            <td class="upper-left" align="left"><img src="/image/blank.gif" alt="" height="20" width="20"></td>
            <td class="upper-center" width="100%"><img src="/image/blank.gif" alt=""height="20" width="20"></td>
            <td class="upper-right" align="right"><img src="/image/blank.gif" alt="" height="20" width="20"></td>
        </tr>    
        <tr valign="top">
            <td class="middle-left"><img src="/image/blank.gif" alt="" height="20" width="20"></td>
            <td width="100%">
                <!-- content below -->

                <!-- content above -->
            </td>
            <td class="middle-right"><img src="/image/blank.gif" alt="" height="20" width="20"></td>
        </tr>        
        <tr valign="top">
            <td class="lower-left" align="left"><img src="/image/blank.gif" alt="" height="20" width="20"></td>
            <td class="lower-center" width="100%"><img src="/image/blank.gif" alt=""height="20" width="20"></td>
            <td class="lower-right" align="right"><img src="/image/blank.gif" alt="" height="20" width="20"></td>
        </tr>        
    </tbody> 
</table>
</body>
```

And CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
body { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
table tbody tr td { background-repeat: repeat; background-position: 0 0; }

.upper-left {background-image: url(/images/b-01-tl.jpg);}
.upper-center {background-image: url(/images/b-01-mt.jpg);}
.upper-right {background-image: url(/images/b-01-tr.jpg);}

.middle-left {background-image: url(/images/b-01-ml.jpg);}
.middle-right {background-image: url(/images/b-01-ml.jpg);}

.lower-left {background-image: url(/images/b-01-bl.jpg);}
.lower-center {background-image: url(/images/b-01-mb.jpg);}
.lower-right {background-image: url(/images/b-01-bl.jpg);}
</style>
```

So on the table itself, we want our border images to align perfectly with each other, that's why we need `cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0"` -- you could probably get away with making sure padding is 0 and border-collapse is set to collapse these days. This kind of table can be as stretchy as you need it to be - it can go full width or be as narrow as (in this example) 60 pixels. Just remember that the width attribute doesn't take "px" as part of the value. So 100% is 100%, but 60px is just 60.

In our middle column we set `width="100%"` for each `<td>` to assure that that last column doesn't accidentally get too wide, we're forcing things to stay the right width - that's why we also use blank gifs for the cells so we can see to the background and get the right size. In some cases we might use `&nbsp;` for this, but those can be unpredictable in size - if you wanted these borders to be only 2 pixels tall, that gets dicey. For a while people were using the actual Netscape `<spacer>` tag, but that never worked very well.

The align="left" and align="right" are in there out of habit, really. If instead of using blank gifs in the left and right `<img>` tags, you used your actual images, well, you could do that.

In this example I'm actually applying the backgrounds using CSS, which, well, I can't think of a browser made in the last 10 years that would not understand this, and it's slightly easier to maintain. I never liked using the `background` attribute, and I bet someday in the future some browsers will eliminate support for it (if they haven't already). This solution looks backward, and forward, in that way. I did a lot of this kind of markup back in the day.

Typically when we did borders like this we'd also include a background color that matched the border somewhat - we'd do that with the `bgcolor` attribute, which you can put on the `<tr>` to specify once, or on the whole table, then override in the cells where you need to. Less markup is always better for this, otherwise you get pretty good with search and replace in your document. The examples from the old Disneyland site unfortunately are not available to me, but http://web.archive.org/web/19980709083315/http://namco.com/ has lot of using tables and spacer gifs to, uh, inspire you.

Comment: I enjoy history lessons like this. Come to think of it, I'm amazed I can remember being ever involved with HTML presentational attributes - I wasn't even a teen back then. Crazy. (Did not mean to make you feel old... honest!)

Comment: Thanks, I managed to make it work :) There are still some glitch in IE6, but I really hope russians are going update their browsers soon

Answer (score 1):

Your code is wrong, you are missing ''

```
-moz-border-image: url('/images/border.png') 20 repeat;
 -webkit-border-image: url('/images/border.png') 20 repeat;
 -o-border-image: url('/images/border.png') 20 repeat;
 border-image: url('/images/border.png') 20 repeat; 
 behavior: url('/css/PIE.htc');
```

Comment: No, that's fine. The quotes aren't necessary.

Comment: Yes, and still IE doesn't support border-image.. How to do that in old fashion way? :)

Comment: @BoltClock Isn't missing '' in the CSS a bad practise? And can missing '' still make it work?

Comment: Earlier versions of IE may not, but you are using HTML5, doesn't that mean you are targeting more recent browsers?

Comment: I target to all browsers, because it is international page and russians still use old versions of ie quite often.. sadly :( p.s. even new versions of ie doesn't support image border, neither ie9..

Comment: @user1384668 you want the old-fashioned way, you got the old fashioned way. Not really how I would do it today, but it should work for you. See my answer.